# Lua - decrementing "class" object count when object is removed from memory

Tags: lua, destructor, counter, moai

I'm currently working on a MOAI project using Lua.  I"m trying to set up some stress tests for some of the game objects, and in turn tracking when the Lua objects I have are created and destroyed during a game session. I can easily track when an "class" object/table has been initialized by incrementing the count in the constructor or initializer. However, because Lua does not have destructors, I'm not sure how I can track when an object has been removed from memory.

Would appreciate any help or suggestions on this matter.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To be notified when a Lua object (I assume full userdata or table) is gone, you set a [_gc metamethod](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.5.1) for it.

Comment: I don't think this will work in MOAI as it uses Lua 5.1.  Also `debug` and `newproxy` are not available.

Comment: @finnw, you're right, if the objects are pure Lua tables, then there is no way to get gc notifications. I thought they were userdata  created in C.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps weak tables is your answer, with nesting. Here's a snippet:

```
objectArray={}

function newObj(...)
   --your OOP code here
   --obj is the new table you made
   objectArray[#objectArray+1]=setmetatable({obj},{__mode='v'})
end
```

Now, in a function/block that runs every frame:

```
for i=1,#objectArray do --no pairs for efficiency, being run every frame this matters
   local stillThere=#objectArray[i]
   stillThere=stillThere==1
   if not stillThere then deconstruct() end
end
```

Unfortunately, you can't get the table back. I'm not sure if there's an easy solution to this, because __index halts GC.